# In c#, text box issue when using custom source

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox

In c#, i have text box with autocomplete source from listView. 
When i am typing the key, the textbox populate the suggestion.
When i am selecting any one of the suggested text from list its working fine.
But when i am trying to move down in the populated list using key board(down arrow), the text box is text is replaced with first item in the list. i cant move to the second item in the list.

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textbox1.Text != "")
    {
        TreeNode treeNode = TreeNode;
        string text = textbox1.Text;
        Boolean isContain = false;

        foreach (TreeNode subNode in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
            if (subNode.Name.StartsWith(text))
            {
                if (subNode.Name.StartsWith(text))
                    suggestStageName.Add(subNode.Name);
                isContain = true;
                if (subNode.Name.Equals(textbox1.Text))
                   do corresponding event
            }
        }
        if (isContain)
        {
            textbox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = suggestStageName;
            textbox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;                 
            textbox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Web or Windows ?

Comment: When you press down arrow you should not change the text in the textbox, instead just highlight the complete option. Replace the text only when an autoreplace option is chosen.

Comment: Window application. I am not changing text, as per inbuilt function the text getting change

Answer (score 3):

This segment shouldn't be inside the textChanged event. You should assign it only once.

```cs
textbox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = suggestStageName;
textbox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;                 
textbox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

EDIT:

Try this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    AutoCompleteStringCollection suggestStageName = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    foreach (TreeNode subNode in treeNode.Nodes)
    {
        suggestStageName.Add(subNode.Name);
    }

    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = suggestStageName;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

}
```

And leave the textChanged event empty. The AutoComplete will do all the work for you.

Comment: But still the problem exist. My problem is , when i am trying to move down the suggested list in textbox, the textbox is replaced with the first items from the suggested list. so the remaining suggested list is gone. Because based on the current text in the textbox only the suggested list is getting populated.

Comment: @user1622088, I have updated the answer. Please improvise it to suit your need.

Comment: In form load event the tree node is empty. :'(

Comment: This answer actually a suggestion because your question is quite confusing, you did mentioned about the source being from a ListView but in your code the source was from a TreeNode.

Comment: am using custom autocomplete source for an text box. I have written my code in the textbox TextChanged event. Based on key press, its suggesting some values, but when i try to move down in the suggested list , the text box value is replaced with the first item from suggestion list.But i dont wont to select the first item. The selection should be done once i have pressed enter key. Any one plz resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you visited [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource.aspx). That is how AutoComplete implementation suggested by MSDN. It also makes easier for others to help if you show where you initialize your TreeNode. About your problem, you will only be able to select the first item because, each time you press the Down Key the TextBox will be autofilled and triggering the TextChanged. Everything will reset but now the TextBox contains your first selection. There several other things going on but that basically what happened.